# Issue with multiplication in C

Tags: c, multiplication

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>



int main(){

char name[]="g9.59e10.01024";
int a = atoi(&name[1]);
int b = atoi(&name[3]);
int c = atoi(&name[6]);
int d = c-2;
int e = pow(10,d);
int f = (100*a+b);

printf("%d",a);
printf("\n");
printf("%d",b);
printf("\n");
printf("%d",c);
printf("\n");
printf("%d",d);
printf("\n");
printf("%d",e);
printf("\n");
printf("%d",f);
printf("\n");


float mass_gal = e*f;



printf("%f",mass_gal);
printf("\n");

}
```

And when I run it i get this output:

9,
   59,
   10,
   8,
   100000000,
   959,
   1410719488.000000

All the number seems to be right, except the last one which should be 95900000000. Why do I get a wrong number there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please change the type from float to long and check the result, It seems that the problem with the size of the float.

Answer (score 4):

The multiplication in the line `float mass_gal = e*f;` happens using integer arithmetic. The result is larger than INT_MAX and it overflows (causing undefined behavior). Then the result is converted to and stored in a float.

Cast the operators to float before performing multiplication.

```
float mass_gal = (float)e * (float)f;
```

The result will not be accurate as the IEEE 754 single precision floating point arithmetic can only accurately represent integers up to the value 2^24.

If you don't want to worry about precision, use an integer type that can represent the result, like a *long long int*.

Comment: If I do that I get 95900000256.000000, which is good but what is that 256 at the end?

Comment: Because even with a float or a double, types have limits and you can handle only value supported by your types. You get this because the value 95900000000 is not handled by the float type. And on your computer, it appears that the nearest value is 95900000256.000000

Comment: i wonder how this compiles! pow is defined for doubles not for ints. You should care for datatypes.

Comment: @mikedu95 but 95900000256 is bigger than the number i need, why can't i get it? or how can i solve this problem?

Comment: @Silviutz say a float uses 32 bits i.e. can represents 4294967295 differents values. But there is an infinity of real numbers and all the possibles values cannot be represented with only 32 bits. On your computer, 95900000000 has no float representation, but the closest value is 95900000256.000000.

Comment: @wegus: double is implicitely converted into int.

Comment: @mikedu95 when someone is learning every implicit thing is bad! When using gcc with -Wall it won't compile and one can read why and learn from it. If learned he might get the idea that he should use long as datatype for his last calculation.

Comment: Casting one operand should be sufficient. Please note that likely, computation is internally done with `double` precision before being rounded back to double.